# Python CDP client using Scapy and Pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, scapy

I am trying to write a Python-based CDP client, similar to WinCDP for those familiar.  For the purposes of troubleshooting compilation I have a significantly shortened version:

```
# Suppress Scapy IPv6 warning
import logging 
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)

import re from scapy.all import *

load_contrib("cdp") class main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.filter = "ether host 01:00:0c:cc:cc:cc"
        self.interfaces = str(ifaces)
        print(self.interfaces)
        try:
            self.p = sniff(count=1,iface='Intel(R) 82578DM Gigabit Network Connection',filter=self.filter,timeout=60)
        except:
            print('OUCH!  Something went wrong.')
        else:
            print('Finished processing...')
            print("DeviceID: {}".format(self.p[0].payload["CDPMsgDeviceID"].val.decode('utf-8')))
            print("PortID: {}".format(self.p[0].payload["CDPMsgPortID"].iface.decode('utf-8')))
            print("NativeVLAN: {}".format(self.p[0].payload["CDPMsgNativeVLAN"].vlan))
            print("IPv4addr: {}".format(self.p[0].payload["CDPAddrRecordIPv4"].addr))
            print("Model: {}".format(self.p[0].payload["CDPMsgPlatform"].val.decode('utf-8')))
            print("Duplex: {}".format(self.p[0].payload["CDPMsgDuplex"].duplex))
            print("VTP Domain: {}".format(self.p[0].payload["CDPMsgVTPMgmtDomain"].val.decode('utf-8')))

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

On all versions of Python I've tried this produces results similar to the following:

```
INDEX  IFACE                                            IP              MAC
10     Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter                 172.31.253.241  78:15:27:01:22:F1
11     Intel(R) 82578DM Gigabit Network Connection      10.X.Y.Z     78:2B:CB:00:11:22
21     Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2              10.0.75.1       00:15:5D:CD:BE:03
26     Npcap Loopback Adapter                           127.0.0.1       00:00:00:00:00:00
4      VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2         192.168.56.1    0A:00:27:00:00:04
9      NETGEAR WNA3100M N300 Wireless Mini USB Adapter                  2C:B0:5D:00:11:22
Finished processing...
DeviceID: switch01
PortID: GigabitEthernet5/0/29
NativeVLAN: 120
IPv4addr: 10.X.Y.Z
Model: cisco WS-C2960X-48FPD-L
Duplex: 1
VTP Domain: XYZ
```

I have managed to get the script to compile and it will run with the following:

```
pyinstaller -F cdpscript.py --hidden-import=queue
```

But, when the executable is run the output is:

```
INDEX  IFACE  IP  MAC
OUCH!  Something went wrong.
```

Which leads me to believe that enough of Scapy is running to print the headers of the ifaces command, but nothing else works.  This was done on Python 3.6.6 as the Pyinstaller documentation indicates this is the most recent version supported, with Scapy 2.4.0 and PyInstaller 3.3.1.

I'm hoping to be able to give my techs an executable on a USB drive they can run and get CDP information without having to install anything locally, similarly to how we had been using WinCDP.  Except, WinCDP has not been playing well with Windows 10 lately.  I am hoping to create our own version so we can do fancier stuff like stick information in a database to track our machines.  At any rate, none of this fun can happen if I can't get the script to compile into a working exe.  Also, does anyone familiar with Scapy know if NPcap is going to have to be installed on the target machines?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi ! I can not reproduce :/ how do you run your executable ? Could you retry using the latest github dev version ? Thanks !